# How to keep the quotes string with configobj in Python

Tags: python, configobj

I have a config file and it has an item as:

```
[time_format]
iso = "ISO (2015-12-31 13:30:55)"
```

I read the config file with configobj as:

```
config = ConfigObj(file_name);
section = config.keys();
```

After some reading, I write the config without modifying the above item as:

```
config.write();
```

The item in the config file becomes:

```
iso = ISO (2015-12-31 13:30:55)
```

The quotes disappear. Is there any way to keep the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and 'fixed' it by subclassing ConfigObj and overwriting the methods that remove and add the quotes -

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

class MyConfigObj(ConfigObj):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ConfigObj.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def _unquote(self, value):
         return value

    def _quote(self, value, multiline=True):
        return value
```

Then use MyConfigObj in place of ConfigObj and config entries with quotation marks are read in and written back without change.

This works on the simple config files I have used, but I imagine on more complex config files (multiline entries, entries with lists etc.) further refinement will be needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`iso = '"ISO (2015-12-31 13:30:55)"'`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not modify this item in the config file because it is used by other module.

Comment: Edit your message and tell us how do you read the file. Put the entire code and specift what can do and what can't you do.